# How many views does all of the stack overflow questions have all together?

Tags: discussion, statistics

I'm a statistics geek. I recently looked through the badges, and realized that an enormous amount of badges has been awarded for number of question views.

As of now we have:

- 2.5m times popular question (1000 views)
- 1.2m of which are Notable questions (2500 views)
- 304k of which are Famous questions (10000 views)

since multiple badges are awarded for a single question, we get

- still 304k famous ones (3.040.000.000)
- 900k notables (2.250.000.000)
- 1.3m popular (1.300.000.000)

In total 6.590.000.000. To me, this number is mind blowingly huge, and I know this is far from the total number of views, as there are 9 million questions unaccounted for, and that the 2.5 million questions I have considered, are calculated with the bare minimum of views they possibly could have.

Is there an accurate number available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to a quick [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/453944/total-number-of-views) I wrote, as of yesterday there were around 18,211,131,029 (18.2 billion) views for non-deleted questions.

Query:

```
select sum(cast(viewCount as bigint)) as totalNumberOfViews
from Posts
where PostTypeId = 1 --questions
```